# Is it possible to know imei number of other mobile using any sort of wireless technology?

Tags: mobile

Are there methods to grab imei numbers of mobiles irrespective of smart or ordinary using Bluetooth or similar wireless technologies. 
Case : other mobile may not have Bluetooth or possibly switched off...

Note : this information is being collected for finding solution to a problem.

Comment: you might get better answers on a mobile tech forum - and the answer might be dependent on the device

Comment: Only via an IMEI Catcher (a device that acts like a base station to trick phones into associating). They are illegal in most (if not all) jurisdictions. The IMEI is protected for the exact reason that you are curious: users don't want their handsets allowing them to be tracked pseudonymously.

Comment: `this information is being collected for finding solution to a problem.` That's awfully vague.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere some nasty ad tracking perhaps?

Comment: @AndréBorie ..or stalking someone perhaps. Lots of nefarious possibilities here.

Answer (score 1):

Businesses that are worried about mobiles being used in unauthorised places uses technology that might be useful to you.

I wrote an answer on the [Academia StackExchange with some products](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/55317/41918) but I think only [AirPatrol](http://airpatrolcorp.com/) (though I note on the site AirPatrol now says they don't collect IMEIs, check with your sales rep) and [Libelium](http://www.libelium.com/products/meshlium/smartphone-detection/) will be relevant. Some of these you can buy multiple sensors to work out which "zone" the mobile device is being used in.

These will typically list the IMEIs of broadcasting devices and as they do not interfere with them or broadcast on licensed spectrum themselves I believe are legal (but IANAL). Still I'd be surprised if they were illegal to operate given they sell them!

Comment: With 4G, IMEI exchange is encrypted. Most communication uses a randomly assigned temporary ID. You can probably get a reliable device _count_. Breaking that encryption would be illegal.